# tf.concat() puts gradient 0?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is there a way to achieve the stick breaking process using tf.scan? Concretely, I have this code for Theano and I am unable to translate this code into Tensorflow. I tried using a standard loop and tensor slicing and concatenating, but I think it fails to get gradients in the optimization.

```
    stick_segment = theano.shared(value=np.zeros((batch_size,), dtype=theano.config.floatX), name='stick_segment')
    remaining_stick = theano.shared(value=np.ones((batch_size,), dtype=theano.config.floatX), name='remaining_stick')

    def compute_latent_vars(i, stick_segment, remaining_stick, v_samples):
        # compute stick segment                                                                                                     
        stick_segment = v_samples[:,i] * remaining_stick
        remaining_stick *= (1-v_samples[:,i])
        return (stick_segment, remaining_stick)

    (stick_segments, remaining_sticks), updates = theano.scan(fn=compute_latent_vars,
                                                              outputs_info=[stick_segment, remaining_stick],sequences=T.arange(latent_size-1),
                                                              non_sequences=[v_samples], strict=True)
```

I was able to transform the Theano code into Tensorflow but I am unable to get the gradients. Namely, the code is:

```
def fn(previous_output,current_input):
    [stick,remaining] = previous_output
    i = current_input
    stick = v[:,i]*remaining
    remaining *= (1-v[:,i])
    return [stick,remaining]

elems = tf.Variable(tf.range(latent-1))
[pi,rem] = tf.scan(fn,elems,initializer=[tf.ones([bs]),tf.ones([bs])])
z = tf.concat([pi,tf.reshape(rem[-1,:],[1,bs])],axis=0)
z = tf.transpose(z)
delt = tf.gradients(z,v)
return z,delt
```

But when I see gradients of pi or rem, they are non-zero. But the moment I see gradients of z, all of them get 0. Is it because of tf.concat? Is there some way to prevent this problem?

Comment: Can you print tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()? Is the gradient None (statically zero) or 0?

Comment: It is exceeding the number of characters allowed. The gradient is in values 0.0 on getting it from sess.run()

Comment: Can you post a little more code? What is v?

Comment: You can assume that v is a node obtained by doing some simple arithmetic operations on a placeholder. It is a tensor of size [bs,latent-1]

Comment: Can you use tfdbg to look at the nodes and find out which ones are zero which you wouldn't expect to be zero?